# Cycles render error

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error

When I try to preview my animation on Concierge Render it gives me this error:
Error: Segmentation fault
I use cycles and picked GPU Compute on render settings.

I contacted the support line they sent me this: Array iterator out of range: Mesh_polygons_lookup_int (index 1099668583) and told me to check out my mesh polygons.

I'm very new to Blender and I couldn't find any information online to solve this issue. Any help is very much appreciated.

If there is any other information I should provide for better assistance please let me know.